# C# container: Row, Index

Tags: c#, indexing, row, containers

I need to create container like this: Container.Add(RowIndex, ValueIndex);

I know Dictionary just have Key and Value and this is not good for me.
And i havent no idea how to use 2 containers to create Row, Index how i want.

So example:

```
Container[Row][Index]:
Container[0][0] = "Apple";
Container[0][1] = "Orange";
Container[1][0] = "Number";
```

Because im trying use this container for read sql. When i got next result it add to current row value +1. And Index mean field value.

In code:

```
                int row = 0;

                while (ObjReader.Read())
                {
                    foreach (var result in ObjReader)
                        ReadList.Add(row, result.ToString());

                    row++;
                }

                ObjReader.NextResult();
```

this is for reading

and now get result to another Class

```
    public string Field(int row, int index)
    {
        return ReadList[row][index];
    }
```

Comment: A bi-dimensional array or a dictionary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you're looking for a `List` of `List`s.

```
List<List<string>> results = new List<List<string>>();

while (haveMoreRows)
{
    List<string> nextRow = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in currentRow)
        nextRow.Add(item.ToString());

    results.Add(nextRow);
}
```

Now you can do something like: `results[2][1]` to get the value at the 3rd row in the 2nd column.

Comment: Only possible problem is that each row can have a different number of columns; this (like most nested collections) is a "jagged" 2-dimensional collection. If you want something more like a table, you'll need to wrap the 2-dimensional list in a custom class that "fixes" the second dimension at however many columns you want the table to have.

Comment: @KeithS If there is a known number of fixed columns then I would instead prefer to have a class representing a row (one property per column) and then have a list (or IEnumerable) of those.  The question seems to imply that there isn't enough information known at the start to do that.

Comment: very true, I was just pointing out the fact that a nested List won't guarantee that any particular column is or isn't available for every row. However, the way he wants to use it should lead to a regular column count among all rows, so it's a totally workable solution and +1.

Comment: Isnt this nonsence? "Now you can do something like: results[2][1] to get the value at the 3rd row in the 2nd column."

Comment: @user1085907 No.  Remember that `List` is 0 indexed, so `results[2]` is the 3rd item.  That will return another list, and using `[1]` on that returned list will get the 2nd item of that 3rd row.

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple pair class:

```
public class Pair<P, T>
{
    public Pair() { }
    public Pair(P first, T second)
    {
        First = first;
        Second = second;
    }
    public P First { get; set; }
    public T Second { get; set; }
}
```

to use:

```
List<Pair<int, string>> ReadList = new List<Pair<int, string>>();
while (ObjReader.Read())
{
    foreach (var result in ObjReader)
        ReadList.Add(new Pair<int, string> {
            First = row, 
            Second = result.ToString()
        });

    row++;
}

ObjReader.NextResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

try with `iterator` and `type anonymous`

iterator use the keyword yield

```
foreach (var result in ObjReader)
{
        yield return result.ToString();
}
```

You will have IEnumerable

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you really want is a [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx). It's a collection of rows and columns specifically designed to represent a database table.